# HTML5 Canvas text not appearing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to display a text on a canvas by entering a message in a textbox but it's not appearing.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
        <input type="text" name="fname" size="50" id="form_val">
        <button onclick="clicked()">Submit</button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function clicked () {
                var x = document.getElementById("form_val");
                return x.value;
            }

            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.font = "25px Verdana";
            ctx.fillText(clicked(), 250, 250);
        </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code outside of your function is triggered immediately, put it inside the function so it's called when it needs to be (as it currently stands, it calls nothing. And when you click the button, it's returning the input value to the onclick method. Try this instead:

```
function clicked(){
   var x=document.getElementById("form_val");
   var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.font="25px Verdana";
   ctx.fillText(x.value,250,250);
}
```

Comment: Yes this works. Thanks. But as i need to do some other things with the canvas like draw images so i have put the declaration of the canvas outside of the clicked() function. Inside only the fillText function remains.

Comment: Move the variables outside the function scope and you'll be alright then

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>

<input type="text" name="fname" size="50" id="form_val">
<button id='submit'>Submit</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");

var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font="25px Verdana";

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', clicked);

function clicked(){
 var x=document.getElementById("form_val");
 // Create the text when the button is clicked
 ctx.fillText(x.value,250,250);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GM6vX/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clicked(){
 var x=document.getElementById("form_val");

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font="25px Verdana";
ctx.fillText(x.value,250,250);
}
```

With this, the text will be filled when clicking the button. Note: I haven't tested the code, but you might get the picture